# how to pass multiple values to routes from controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**route**

```
Route::get('/dashboard/view-sub-project/{pid}/{sid}', 'SubProjectController@view')->name('sub-project.view')->middleware('auth');
```

**View**

```
<a href="{{ route('sub-project.view', request()->route()->parameters['id'] . '/' . $update->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary project-view">View</a>
```

Values of var

`request()->route()->parameters['id']` is 2

`$update->id` is 1

I have defined router correctly on web.php and view but still, it throws an error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: sub-project.view] [URI:
>   dashboard/view-sub-project/{pid}/{sid}]. (View:
>   /var/www/html/groot-server/resources/views/project/view.blade.php)

I have tried to change my router like this also

```
Route::get('/dashboard/view-sub-project/{pid}{sid}', 'SubProjectController@view')->name('sub-project.view')->middleware('auth');
```

Still got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding parameters in array.

```
   Route::get('/dashboard/view-sub-project/{pid}/{sid}','SubProjectController@view')
       ->name('sub-project.view')
       ->middleware('auth');




   <a href="{{ route('sub-project.view', 
          [
             'pid' => request()->route()->parameters['id'], 
             'sid' => $update->id 
          ]
     ) }}" class="btn btn-primary project-view">
     View
   </a>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

On your view, since you're using the route function to build the url you can do the following.

```
<a href="{{ route('sub-project.view', [
                        'pid' => request()->route()->parameters['id'],
                        'sid' => '$update->id'
                  ]) }}" class="btn btn-primary project-view">View</a>
```

You can also view it in the [Laravel Helper Function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-route).

If you only have one parameter in the route you can just pass the value. Let's say you had a route that only took a post ID, `Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit')->name(edit)`. On your view you can then do `{{ route('edit', $post->id) }}`.

When you have multiple values being passed to the route url as you have in your case you pass an array of item with the key being the same as the route parameter.

Let's say you have another route `Route::get('/posts/{post}/comments/{comment}')->name(post.comment)`. On your view you can do `{{ route('post.comment', ['post' => $post->id, 'commment' => $comment->id]) }}`.